# somar linha específica em Mysql

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, query

Fala pessoa!

Estou fazendo a inserção de um tempo (hora:minutos:segundos) em uma coluna x, gostaria de saber se é possível somar o valor atual da linha com o próximo valor que for inserido? como se fosse um += . Por exemplo: Uma linha do IDx da Coluna Tempo, ela recebe um valo de 01:00:00 e depois recebe o valor de 20 minutos, ou seja, 01:20:00. fazer isso sem a necessidade de fazer uma query na linha e somar com o novo valor e então fazer um update.
Obrigado.

A tabela é a seguinte:

```
# nomeID       situação      tempo    tTotal

127.0.0.1       Disponi    00:00:10  00:00:00
192.168.1.102   Ocupada    00:00:00  00:00:00
192.168.1.103   Disponi    01:26:00  01:26:00
192.168.1.104   Ocupada    00:00:00  00:00:00
```

Comment: Pode posta sua tabela?

Comment: Acrescentei a tabela!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digamos que o novo valor a ser somado seja de 20 min -> 00:20:00 e o id seja 1, então ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
UPDATE tabela
SET tTempo = SEC_TO_TIME( TIME_TO_SEC(tTempo) + TIME_TO_SEC('00:20:00') )
WHERE id = '1'
```

Comment: A questão é que o tempo 01:00:00 já vai estar na minha database, o que eu gostaria de fazer era que na próxima vez que um outro tempo for inserido ele fizesse a soma com o que já está no banco.

Comment: Ok. Na tabela já tem uma linha que o tempo é 01:00:00. Daí você vai inserir outra linha com 00:20:00, mas não quer essa nova linha fique com 00:20:00 e sim, que ela some com a anterior, ficando essa nova linha com 01:20:00. É isso?

Comment: Exatamente isso!

Comment: Editei a resposta, veja se assim serve.

Comment: Quase isso, só que ele está criando uma nova linha sem o ID e com o valor somado

Comment: É só colocar no INSERT todos os campos que você povoar na tabela. Veja lá como ficou com mais dois campos.

Comment: Mas dessa forma eu tenho que inserir novos valores a esses campos? ou eu consigo modificar apenas o campo tempo?

Comment: Se vais inserir uma nova linha, o correto é alimentar todos os campos necessários. Pelo que você tá falando então você não vai fazer um INSERT e sim um UPDATE.

Comment: Exatamente, a ideia é somar o valor do campo com o novo valor, na mesma linha na coluna tTotal. somando o valor tempo com o valor que já está em tTotal

Comment: Blz @LeoneAzevedo, modifiquei novamente o sql, agora para um UPDATE.

Comment: Olá, fiz de maneira diferente mas foi útil pra  eu chegar no resultado. Obrigado.